# How would i properly select the <img src="images/login.png" width="40" height="40" onmousedown="return false;" alt="Login" /> line in my code?

Tags: css

I have used the code below to attempt to select this line of code:

```css
body >div first-child + div + div > img {
  }
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="profilebartr">
            <div class="login">
                <a href="google.com">
                    <img src="images/login.png" width="40" height="40" onmousedown="return false;" alt="Login" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I'm still learning something in CSS, sorry.

And my preview box no longer shows the previews for anything after running code snippets, sorry.

Comment: you could see [css selectors](https://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/) for more information on selectors. Also its better to use specific class or id for that element and apply the css for that element  only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/tmbwk27c/

The `>` operator only refers to the immediate children and, in this case, you `img` is not direct child of the `div`. This is the reason it is not working. Once go through: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

```
body > div:first-child > div > div  img {
    background-color:black;
    padding:10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check out the link.